# Why does initramfs need to overmount rootfs with the new root?

Tags: linux, mount, boot, initramfs

I read the [linux documentation on initramfs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/v5.6/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt) and the [source code](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/switch_root.c) of `switch_root`.

The documentation says:

> When switching another root device, initrd would pivot_root and then
>     umount the ramdisk.  But initramfs is rootfs: you can neither pivot_root
>     rootfs, nor unmount it.  Instead delete everything out of rootfs to
>     free up the space (find -xdev / -exec rm '{}' ';'), **overmount rootfs
>     with the new root (cd /newmount; mount --move . /; chroot .)**, attach
>     stdin/stdout/stderr to the new /dev/console, and exec the new init.

And `switch_root` really does so:

```
if (chdir(newroot)) {
    warn(_("failed to change directory to %s"), newroot);
    return -1;
}

...

if (mount(newroot, "/", NULL, MS_MOVE, NULL) < 0) {
    close(cfd);
    warn(_("failed to mount moving %s to /"), newroot);
    return -1;
}

...

if (chroot(".")) {
    close(cfd);
    warn(_("failed to change root"));
    return -1;
}
```

Why do we need to move the mount point over `/`?
Why isn't chrooting to new_root sufficient?

Comment: Maybe because of chroot break: [1](http://www.ouah.org/chroot-break.html) [2](https://filippo.io/escaping-a-chroot-jail-slash-1/) [3(pdf)](https://deepsec.net/docs/Slides/2015/Chw00t_How_To_Break%20Out_from_Various_Chroot_Solutions_-_Bucsay_Balazs.pdf)

Comment: @A.B Thanks, it really prevents it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### **Edit**: edited thanks to @timothy-baldwin.

Mounting `new_root` over `/` changes the root directory of the mount namespace, chrooting without overmounting `/` will cause the system to be in a `chroot` environment (where the root directory does not match the root directory of the mount namespace).

This will cause some problems, for example:

#### 1. Creating user namespaces is not allowed when inside chroot.

According to `man 2 unshare`, `unshare`ing user namespace will fail with `EPERM` when in chroot environment.

> ```
> EPERM (since Linux 3.9)
>       CLONE_NEWUSER was specified in flags and the caller is in a  chroot  environment
>       (i.e., the  caller's root directory does not match the root directory of the
>       mount namespace in which it resides).
> ```

```
$ unshare -U
unshare: unshare failed: Operation not permitted
```

#### 2. Entering a mount namespace will set the root directory to the namespace's root directory

Entering a mount namespace sets the root directory of the process to the root directory of the mount namespace, so doing `setns` to our mount namespace will set our root directory to the rootfs directory.

```
$ nsenter -m/proc/self/ns/mnt /bin/sh
$ ls -ld /new_root
new_root
```

I can see new_root directory which is outside my chroot.

#### Mounting over `/` does not really prevent escaping the chroot

The root user can `umount` this directory, re-entering its mount namespace (`setns`) and see the rootfs:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int ns = open("/proc/self/ns/mnt", O_RDONLY);
    if (ns == -1) {
        perror("open");
        goto out;
    }

    if (umount2("/", MNT_DETACH)) {
        perror("umount2");
        goto out;
    }

    if (setns(ns, CLONE_NEWNS)) {
        perror("setns");
        goto out;
    }

    char *a[] = { "/bin/sh", NULL };
    char *e[] = { NULL };
    execve(a[0], a, e);

    perror("execve");

out:
    return 1;
}
```

```
$ gcc -o main main.c
$ unshare -m ./main
/ # ls -d new_root
new_root
/ # mount -t proc proc /proc
/ # cat /proc/mounts
none / rootfs rw 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
```

<s>Mounting `new_root` over `/` is necessary in order to prevent chroot escapes.</s>

Created a minimal initramfs and replaces `switch_root` binary with this shell script to get a shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /bin/sh
```

Also changed `/bin/sh` inside the initramfs to a statically linked `busybox`.

Compiled the following code and linked it statically:

```c
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int fd = open(".", O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        goto out0;
    }

    if (chroot("tmp")) {
        perror("chroot");
        goto out1;
    }

    if (fchdir(fd)) {
        perror("fchdir");
        goto out1;
    }

    if (chdir("..")) {
        perror("chdir");
        goto out1;
    }

    char *const argvp[] = { "sh", NULL };
    char *const envp[] = { NULL };
    execve("bin/sh", argvp, envp);

    perror("execve");

out1:
    close(fd);

out0:
    return  1;

}
```

Places in my real root filesystem's root directory as `/escape`.

Rebooted and got a shell just before the `switch_root` takes place.

### Without overmounting root

```
$ mount --move proc new_root/proc
$ mount --move dev new_root/dev
$ mount --move sys new_root/sys
$ mount --move run new_root/run
$ exec chroot new_root
$ ./escape
$ ls -d new_root
new_root
```

I escaped the chroot.

### With overmounting root

```
$ mount --move proc new_root/proc
$ mount --move dev new_root/dev
$ mount --move sys new_root/sys
$ mount --move run new_root/run
$ cd new_root
$ mount --move . /
$ exec chroot .
$ ./escape
$ ls -d new_root
ls: cannot access 'new_root': No such file or directory
```

I cannot escape the chroot.

Comment: Root can escape this chroot by unmounting the root directory (not possible in a less privileged user namespace): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152029/why-is-there-no-rootfs-file-system-present-on-my-system

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin What does re-entering its own mount namespace do? Something other than nothing?

Comment: @Melab It sets the root and current directory to the root of the mount namespace. See this Q&A: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452384/i-dont-understand-how-entering-a-mount-namespace-can-work

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin Has that security hole been patched up?

Comment: @Melab What security hole?

Answer (score 1):

Not overmounting rootfs breaks user and mount namespaces:

- The `setns` system call will set the callers root directory to root
  directory of the mount namespace, undoing `chroot`.
- If the process root directory is not the root directory of it's mount
  namespace creating a user namespace by an unprivileged process is forbidden.

Comment: Did you mean `setns` syscall? And what do you by "unprivileged process is forbidden"?

Comment: @IdanYadgar I've added the missing words.